# Monkey-patching in Python

Tags: python, class, monkeypatching

I have a module `THIRDPARTY` with various classes and functions:

```
def multi(n1, n2):
    result = n1 * n2
    return result

class Spam():

    def original_function(self, num1, num2):
        result = multi(num1, num2)
        new_result = result + result
        print(new_result)
```

I imported the module with:
import THIRDPARTY as tp

Now, I want to replace the `original_function` in class Spam with the following:

```
def original_function(self, num1, num2):
    result = multi(num1, num2) 
    new_result = num1 - num2
    print(new_result)
```

Please note the different mathematical operations in the `original_function`. What I tried but didn't work:

```
tp.Spam.originalfunction = originalfunction
```

However, it doesn't inherit the other classes and functions (e.g. `def multi`).

Comment: `original_function`, both the original function and your version, doesn't do anything useful: it only assigns something to a local variable which gets lost at the end of the function. Did you mean `return num1 - num2` or `self.result = num1 - num2`, or maybe even something else?

Comment: I edited my original post to make clear. The output of the function is not important here. The difference between the initial and new function is the mathematical operator.

Comment: Create a `Spam` subclass that does what you want (i.e. implements its own `original_function()` method), then replace the `THIRDPARTY` module's `Spam` class with this derived class.

Comment: It sounds like you expect that your replacement function has access to the same scope as the original function. It doesn't work that way. Your replacement function still lives in the scope where it is defined. If you want to access functions from THIRDPARTY, you have to do that explicitly like in any other case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you haven't imported `multi()` as `multi()`. Try `tp.multi()` instead of `multi()`

Here is an example:

```py
# ------in module.py file------

def multi(inp1, inp2):
    return inp1 + inp2

class A():
    def func1(self):
        print(multi(3, 4))
```

```py
# ------in current file------

# what you're currently doing:

import module as md

def func1(self):
        print(multi(3, 4) + 10)


md.A.func1 = func1
class1 = A()
class1.func1()  # NameError: name 'multi' is not defined
```

```py
# ------in current file------

# the fix:

import module as md

def func1(self):
        print(md.multi(3, 4) + 10)


md.A.func1 = func1
class1 = A()
class1.func1()
```

If that doesn't work, it might help to show us the actual function because there could be crucial details you're leaving out.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey-patching working well. I tried to make it with Flask and I got the result.

```
import flask

def mult(self, n1, n2):
    print(n1 * n2)

flask.Flask.before_request = mult

obj = flask.Flask('name')
obj.before_request(3, 4)  # 12
```

Comment: The problem still persists. I edited my original post to make it clear.